# Is there a way to turn cursor acceleration off on MacBook's trackpad (not for mouse) with using Terminal?

Tags: trackpad, cursor

I turned acceleration off on mouse but there is not an option for trackpad to turn it off. I don't want to download 3rd party software to fix this problem, is it possible to solve it with Terminal?

I also tried `defaults write .GlobalPreferences com.apple.mouse.scaling -1` command but I think it is for mouse and that's why it didn't work.

Comment: @Tetsujin I don't think It actually does. I think the question is about disabling cursor acceleration, not making the tracking speed faster.

Comment: @Thinkr - The OP on the link asked for 'speed' but *got* acceleration…scaling. Exactly as the OP here asked for, but for trackpad.

Comment: @Tetsujin Well I understand that they're talking about the same thing but the only thing is that the OP on the question wants to increase that speed whereas the OP here wants to disable it. I still don't get why they are considered to be the same question. Also, what do you mean by "asked for 'speed' but *got* acceleration...scaling"?

Comment: @Thinkr - The OP here knew what they were looking for, just didn't know its name. The dupe has the same answer, even though that's not what the OP over there thought they were asking for. Duplicates ideally link two search ideas to one answer suitable to both.

Comment: @Tetsujin Oh. Thanks for this explanation.